# position and orientation of the vector

Tags: ros, position

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I went through tf tutorial and some questions here http://answers.ros.org/question/39250/getting-the-position-and-the-pose-of-robot-using-tf_listener/) . I assume that my robot is an rectangle so want to know the position of each 4 vectors of my rectangle.

In my code to get the distance between the fixed point in the map and the center of the robot, center of the base link ( which is the centar of that rectangle I did not used a pose. I used this code. And think is ok.

```
while (node.ok()){
    tf::StampedTransform transform;
    try{
      listener.lookupTransform("/base_link", "/door1",  
                               ros::Time(0), transform);
    }
    catch (tf::TransformException ex){
      ROS_ERROR("%s",ex.what());
    }

    double x = transform.getOrigin().x();
    double y = transform.getOrigin().y();
    double dist = sqrt(x*x + y*y);
```

So , but I need to calculate the distance between the 4 vectors (which are formed by the 4 corner points of the rectangle) to that fixed point. So how to get that vectors fist, with the help of my previous code and than the distance.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41959/position-and-orientation-of-the-vector/) by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2012-08-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The best way to solve your problem is to use the transformation directly itself. You know the transformation between `base_link` and `door1` in your code, so you can specify the points in the `base_link` and transform them into the `door1` coordinate frame (untested code below)

EDIT: Didn't realize you needed just the distances. Distances can be computed in either frame of reference. In the example below we'll use the `door1` frame of reference.

```
tf::StampedTransform transform; 
try { 
  listener.lookupTransform("/base_link", "/door1", ros::Time(0), transform); 
} catch (tf::TransformException ex){ 
  ROS_ERROR("%s",ex.what()); 
}

tf::Vector3 pt1(robot_length/2, robot_breadth/2, 0);
tf::Vector3 pt2(robot_length/2, -robot_breadth/2, 0);
tf::Vector3 pt3(-robot_length/2, -robot_breadth/2, 0);
tf::Vector3 pt4(-robot_length/2, robot_breadth/2, 0);

tf::Transform tf_base_link_to_door = transform.Inverse();

tf::Vector3 door1_pt(0, 0, 0);
tf::Vector3 required_pt1 = tf_base_link_to_door * pt1;
float dist_pt1 = required_pt1.distance(door1_pt);
tf::Vector3 required_pt2 = tf_base_link_to_door * pt2;
float dist_pt2 = required_pt2.distance(door1_pt);
tf::Vector3 required_pt3 = tf_base_link_to_door * pt3;
float dist_pt3 = required_pt3.distance(door1_pt);
tf::Vector3 required_pt4 = tf_base_link_to_door * pt4;
float dist_pt4 = required_pt4.distance(door1_pt);
```

---

Originally posted by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) with karma: 2871 on 2012-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-08-22**:
Sorry but where you calculate the distance here???

**Comment by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) on 2012-08-23**:
@Astronaut: see updated answer

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-08-23**:
Yes, I need the distances between the four vectors( create from the 4 corners of the rectangle) and the fixed object(door) in the map. So in this case the four distances are dist_pt1, dist_pt2, dist_pt3 and dist_pt4, wright??

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-08-23**:
But dont understand. The door has fixed coordinate in the map frame, for example (1,1,0).  So what means here tf::Vector3 door1_pt(0, 0, 0); ??? float dist_pt1..4 gives me the distance between that door in the map and the robot (robot is moving in the map). Yes?

**Comment by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) on 2012-08-23**:
@Astronaut: The transform from base link to door converts all points to a frame of reference that originates at door1, hence I've used 0,0,0 in the code above. And yes, the distance calculated should be what you need. I recommend reading a bit more about tf at http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-08-23**:
Ok. Understand But need the distance between the line segment (formed by the 4 corners of the recatngle ) and the door. So that distances are dist_pt1, dist_pt2, dist_pt3 and dist_pt4 from the line segment to the door yes??

**Comment by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) on 2012-08-24**:
@Astronaut: The distances are to the 4 corner that make up the robot, if that is what you mean by line segments.

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-08-24**:
I mean i need the distance between the door( a fixed frame in the map) and the 4 line segments (made by the 4 corners of the robot). So i have to know all those 4 distances and find the minimum between all 4 . Understand?

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-08-24**:
No, I do not want a distance to the 4 corner that make up the robot. I want a distance to the 4 line segments that make up the robot( that are make up by the 4 corners of the robot). Understand.?So  need distance from door (point) to the 4 line segments ( make up by the 4 robot corners). OK?

**Comment by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) on 2012-08-27**:
@Astronaut: This is a question to google. Here is the first link that came up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/849211/shortest-distance-between-a-point-and-a-line-segment You should be able to use this to calculate the distances.